# How to validate timestamp format in Athena?

Tags: timestamp, amazon-athena

We have different timestamp formats.

```
yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz
MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy   
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ   
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
etc...
```

I would need to check if the timestamp is stored in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS using an sql in Athena. Is there anyway to validate as such? I can validate if it's a timestamp using typeof function but need to validate the format type.

Comment: You mean you have varchars storing timestamps in provided formats, yes?

Comment: Nope its a timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parse_datetime` with corresponding format wrapped in `try` (which will return `null` in case of failure):

```sql
WITH dataset(ts) AS (
    values 
        ('2021-08-22 03:04:05.000'),
        ('2021-08-22 03:04:05'),
        ('2021-22-08 03:04:05.000'),
        to_iso8601(timestamp '2021-08-22 03:04:05.000')
)

select try(parse_datetime(ts, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')) IS NOT NULL is_in_format
from dataset
```

Output:

| is_in_format |
| --- |
| true |
| false |
| false |
| false |

Comment: Thanks! but since it's a timestamp I get the error "Unexpected parameters (timestamp, varchar(23)) for function parse_datetime.

Comment: I have a table in which data is stored for example :- tableA with a columnA value - 2021-10-10 14:01:02.564 . Now I need to make sure the format of that particular column always remain - 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' and do not change to lets say- yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss for which I need to write a query

Comment: @Vipin AFAIK timestamps are always stored in the same format and you can control varchar transformation with `format_datetime`/`date_format` (and needed format). Am I wrong? Can you show some counterexamples? Otherwise your question does not make a lot of sense to me.